# Apex Batch Unexpected token '{' in dynamic SOQL

Tags: apex

I have some apex code thats supposed to accept a String query variable. Now in my trigger when im assigning this variable I get the Unexpected toke error below:

```
16:59:43:145 USER_DEBUG [26]|DEBUG|query = SELECT Id, StageName, AccountId, Thank_You_email_sent__c FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId != null AND (StageName = 'Posted' AND Thank_You_email_sent__c = false) AND Id IN : {0068E000003VS7pQAG}
```

Which is weird because I was under the impression this worked. Im sure im missing something silly. Can someone help. Below is my trigger as well as the batch apex class

Trigger:

```
trigger DonationUpdate on Opportunity (after update,after insert) {
    //Send emails to donors of the donation account
    System.debug('Total Number of SOQL Queries allowed in this Apex code context: ' +  Limits.getLimitQueries());
    System.debug('Total Number of records that can be queried  in this Apex code context: ' +  Limits.getLimitDmlRows());
    System.debug('Total Number of DML statements allowed in this Apex code context: ' +  Limits.getLimitDmlStatements() );
    System.debug('Total Number of CPU usage time (in ms) allowed in this Apex code context: ' +  Limits.getLimitCpuTime());
    System.debug('');

    Map<Id, Opportunity> donations = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(
        [
            SELECT Id, StageName, AccountId, Thank_You_email_sent__c 
            FROM Opportunity
            WHERE AccountId != null AND 
                (StageName = 'Posted' AND Thank_You_email_sent__c = false) AND
                Id IN : Trigger.newMap.keySet()
        ]
    );
    if (!donations.isEmpty()) {
        //Execute batch
        Set<Id> donationIds = donations.keySet();
        String query = 'SELECT Id, StageName, AccountId, Thank_You_email_sent__c ' +
            'FROM Opportunity ' +
            'WHERE AccountId != null AND ' + 
                '(StageName = \'Posted\' AND Thank_You_email_sent__c = false) AND ' +
                'Id IN : ' + donationIds;
        System.debug('query = ' + query);
        DonationTriggerHandler.SendThankYouEmail(query);
    }

    System.debug('');
    System.debug('1. Number of Queries used in this Apex code so far: ' + Limits.getQueries());
    System.debug('2. Number of rows queried in this Apex code so far: ' + Limits.getDmlRows());
    System.debug('3. Number of DML statements used so far: ' +  Limits.getDmlStatements());    
    System.debug('4. Amount of CPU time (in ms) used so far: ' + Limits.getCpuTime());    

}
```

Batch Apex:

```
global class DonationSendThankYouEmail implements Database.Batchable<SObject>{
    global final String query;
    global final EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [
        SELECT Id, Name 
        FROM EmailTemplate 
        WHERE DeveloperName = 'Thank_you_HTML_Contact'
    ];
    //Get all organisation type account records
    global final Map<Id, Account> organisations = new Map<Id, Account>(
        [
            SELECT Id, Name 
            FROM Account 
            WHERE RecordTypeId IN : 
            [
                SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType 
                WHERE SobjectType = 'Account' AND DeveloperName = 'Organization' LIMIT 1
            ]          
        ]
    ); 
    //Get all person account type account records
    global final Map<Id, Account> persons = new Map<Id, Account>(
        [
            SELECT Id, Name, PersonContactId
            FROM Account 
            WHERE IsPersonAccount = true         
        ]
    );
    //Get all person account contact records
    global final Map<Id, Contact> contacts = new Map<Id, Contact>(
        [
            SELECT Id, Email 
            FROM Contact
            WHERE AccountId IN : persons.keySet()
        ]
    );

    global DonationSendThankYouEmail(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope) {
        //Send Emails
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] emailList = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{}; 
        System.debug('scope = ' + scope);
        Set<Account> donationOrganisations = new Set<Account>();
        for (Opportunity donation : (List<Opportunity>)scope) {
            Account organisation = organisations.get(donation.AccountId);
            System.debug('organisation = ' + organisation);
            if (organisation != null) {
                donationOrganisations.add(organisation);
            }
        }
        System.debug('donationOrganisations = ' + donationOrganisations);
        organisations.clear();
        for (Account organisation : donationOrganisations) {
            System.debug('organisation = ' + organisation);
            organisations.put(organisation.Id, organisation);
        }
        System.debug('donationOrganisations = ' + organisations);
        //Get donation organisation affiliated accounts
        Map<Id, Affiliated_Account__c> donationOrganisationaffiliatedAccounts = new Map<Id, Affiliated_Account__c>(
            [
                SELECT Id, Person_Account__c, Organisation_Account__c
                FROM Affiliated_Account__c 
                WHERE Organisation_Account__c IN : organisations.keySet()          
            ]
        );
        System.debug('donationOrganisationaffiliatedAccounts = ' + donationOrganisationaffiliatedAccounts);
        //Send emails
        for (Opportunity donation : (List<Opportunity>)scope) {
            Account organisation = organisations.get(donation.AccountId); 
            for (Affiliated_Account__c affiliate : donationOrganisationaffiliatedAccounts.values()) {
                if (affiliate.Organisation_Account__c == organisation.Id) {
                    Account affiliateAccount = persons.get(affiliate.Person_Account__c);
                    Contact affiliatedContact = contacts.get(affiliateAccount.PersonContactId);
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    mail.setTargetObjectId(affiliatedContact.Id);
                    mail.setWhatId(donation.Id);
                    mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
                    mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);                                
                    mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{affiliatedContact.Email});
                    emailList.add(mail);               
                }
            }           
        }
        if(!emailList.isEmpty()){
            System.debug('DonationEmailList: '+ emailList);
            try{                
                //Send Emails
                List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> msg = Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);
                for (Opportunity donation : (List<Opportunity>)scope) {
                    donation.Thank_You_email_sent__c = true;
                }
                update scope;
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('Exception caught:::'+e.getMessage());
            }
        }             
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        AsyncApexJob a = [
            SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
            FROM AsyncApexJob
            WHERE Id =: BC.getJobId()
        ];

        //Send an email to the Apex job's submitter notifying job completion
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {a.CreatedBy.Email};            
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            mail.setSubject('Record Clean Up Status: ' + a.Status);
        mail.setPlainTextBody(
            'The batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems +
             ' batches with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.'
        );
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }

}
```

I believe the issue is with this section of code:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a problem like this, passing the ID values in a collection to the Batchable and using the `:` binding mechanism is cleaner than trying to build all the values into a query string. Also, although the Batchable documentation example uses a string for the the query in the `start` method, it usually makes sense to use normal static SOQL and so benefit from compile time checking.

Those changes together would result in:

```
public class XyzBatchable implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

    private Set<Id> opportunityIds;

    public MyBatchable(Set<Id> opportunityIds) {
        this.opportunityIds = opportunityIds;
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
                SELECT Id, StageName, AccountId, Thank_You_email_sent__c 
                FROM Opportunity
                WHERE AccountId != null
                AND StageName = 'Posted'
                AND Thank_You_email_sent__c = false
                AND Id IN :opportunityIds
                ]);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A few issues:

1. The `IN` syntax uses parentheses (`()`), not curly braces (`{}`).
2. Merge syntax (`:`) is only for context values, it looks like you are trying to use a literal.
3. You also need to wrap literal values in single quotes (`''`).

Valid filters:

```
WHERE Id IN ('0068E000003VS7pQAG')
WHERE Id IN (:someContextId)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `:` in your Select statement is expecting a variable not a value. Since you are dynamically building your query with the value the `:` token needs to be removed. As well as replacing the `{}`'s with '`()`'s.